# Thunderbird 12.0.1 doesn't recognize any of my emails on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64

Tags: thunderbird, email

I'm trying to set my emails on thunderbird but I keep getting the same error message:

> Thunderbird failed to find the settings for your email account.

I saw another thread of two people with the same problem but I couldn't find the solution to this problem. I'm sure I'm writing  my profiles correctly.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem is related to temporary maintenance of thunderbird since I could create my emails today. []'s

Comment: Yes, I agree. I've no clue what was going on, but I agree - I was trying to get Tbird to work a few days ago, but I could get it to work yesterday - no software updates or anything, so it's weird. *shrug*